# Reference cells in data.frame or matrix to create a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe, matrix, cell

What is the syntax for referencing individual cells in a matrix? I would like to reference individual cells in an R data.frame to create functions. For example, say I have a 2x2 matrix with the values

```
3 4
5 6
```

and I want to create a function that will do `((3 + 4)/(3 + 4 + 5))`. I've tried doing it as a function and as creating a new variable without success.

`Subj_2_block_4a$HRLR0 <- c(2,2)+c(2,4)` gives me four observations under a new variable.

`Subj_2_block_4a$HRLR0 <- ((2:2 + 2:4) / (2:2 + 2:4 + 2:1 +2:3))` takes these as references to matrices rather than cells.

`Subj_2_block_4a$HRLR0 <- nrow2:ncol2 + nrow2:ncol4`; doesn't work at all.

I've found plenty of resources for adding columns or rows from different matrices, but haven't found any clear explanations on how to write mathematical functions using cells within ONE matrix.

Comment: Just updated my answer to show you more ways to make reference to specific cells.. take a look

Answer (score 1):

## Making reference to an element in a matrix

If you want to build a matrix, you do

```
mtrx <- matrix(c(3,4,5,6), # the data elements 
               nrow=2,              # number of rows 
               ncol=2,              # number of columns 
               byrow = TRUE)        # will format in the way you want 
 
#Take a look in your matrix by just doing this:

mtrx                      # print your matrix 
>      [,1] [,2]  
> [1,]    3    4    
> [2,]    5    6
```

And finaly, if you want to reference the element at the row X, column Y, that can be accessed by  mtrx[X, Y]. In your case:

```
# Your second row, second col:

mtrx[2, 2]      # element at 2nd row, 2rd column 
> [1] 6
```

If you want to see the entire row or the entire column, that is possible too

```
mtrx[2, ]  #  entire second row  
mtrx [ ,2] # entire second column
```

And you can also make reference to more than one element at a time... Lets create a larger matrix for that

```
#Creating a 3x3 matrix
Lmtrx<-matrix(c(3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,6),ncol = 3,nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
Lmtrx # prit to take a look

#Making reference to two columns at once: 1rst and 3rd
Lmtrx[ ,c(1,3)]
```

## Making reference to a cel in a data frame

To make reference to a cell in a `data.frame` instead of a matrix, is quite easy as well:

```
df$col1[1] # First row in first column
df[1,1]  # First row in first column, another way to get it
df$col1  # entire first column
df[ ,1]  # entire first column, another way to get it
df[1, ]  # entire first row
```